# Fastest way to order a huge vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, vector

I am looking for the fastest way to order a multidimensional vector of 220000 * 7 * 6.

I am ordering by the [x][5][y] and I have to make all the value of the middle (7) vector follow up.

```
for(int i =0;i<211876;i++){
    for(int k =0;k<211876;k++){
        if(vec[k][5][myposition] < vec[k+1][5][myposition]){
            for(int n =0;n<7;n++){
            swap2int(vec[k][n][myposition],vec[k+1][n][myposition]);}
        }
    }
}

void swap2int(int &one, int& two){
    int temp=0;
    temp = one;
    one = two;
    two = temp;

    return;
}
```

this is somewhat very slow and I am looking for ways to improve the speed of this.

Comment: Please clean up the code.  I don't see where "i" is used, and there is no definition for "myposition" anywhere.  It looks to me like you're simply sorting each "row" of the array independently, which should be doable with a standard sort and maybe a custom iterator type.  But without details about what is being done we can't help.

Comment: Looks like you've implemented bubble sort, which is notoriously slow. Check out this [list of popular sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Summaries_of_popular_sorting_algorithms). Basically any of them will be faster than what you've got.

Comment: ...unless you really need to, writing your own sort is duplicated effort, and you should use '<algorithm>', and use std::sort (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

Comment: You're doing quadratic sort, so no surprise it's slow. Change your data structure so you can use `std::sort` which is O(N log N). The easiest way to do that would be to reorder the dimensions, so it's vec[myposition][k][n].

Answer (score 4):

Always use `std::sort` unless you have a *very* good reason not to. `std::sort` allows you to supply your own sorting criterion if necessary, so there are hardly any reasons not to use it. You may need to provide a stride iterator in your case, but those are straightforward.

Comment: Would std::sort do a O(N) style sort if possible, or is it going to grab a O(nlog n) variety?

Answer (score 0):

You can always put them inside a min heap (creating a min (or max) heap from a vector takes O(n) on average), then, you can simply extract numbers from your min heap in perfect order, with O(log n) cost for each top()+pop() operation. That way, you'll get a nice O(N log N) cost, you'll play with heaps, which are always interesting, and might have more fun (and add some bug that will make you post here again) than if you just used std::sort :P

Or you can use std::sort as said before, and forget everything else ;)

Btw: In your swap2int() function, there is no need to waste time assigning 0 to temp if you won't use it. Just change it to:

int temp;
temp=one;

or straight to:

int temp=one;